Seeking more elliptic curves such that 3 points satisfy a unique relationship
Let $E(n) = [0, 0, 0, n^2, 0]$ be an elliptic curve in Weierstrass format. This curve is not to be confused with the congruent number elliptic curve $[0,0,0,-n^2,0]$.
$E(n) \quad y^2 = x(x^2+n^2) = [0,0,0,n^2,0] \tag{1}$
Recently a colleague and myself studied Heron triangles with square sides and we found out that these special triangles are connected to this curve (1).
Carefully consider the following algorithm to derive n for the elliptic curve from a give rational value r.
Example:
Let $r = 1/10 = n/d$, i.e $n=1$, $d=10$
and let $P = nd(n^2+d^2) = 1010$
then let $f = core(P)$ (square free part of P) $= 1010$,
Then let
$E(r) = E(1/10) = [0,0,0,1010^2,0] = [0,0,0,1020100,0]$
This is a rank=2 curve, conductor = 8160800, and a Mordell-Weil basis  of [[101,10201],[24745/144,23207275/1728]] It has regulator 12.5810774707.. and SHA = 1 (found by running the l-series).
If we consider the rational points on this curve, we can find other half-angle tangent triads, such as



$\frac{1}{2}$-angle tangent triad
Heron triangle sides
squares




[1/10, 1659/3812, 361/202]
[855625, 3682561, 3162054]
2


[1/10, 202/361, 3408/2381]
[855625, 3682561, 4057224]
2


[1/10, 30599/102050, 9801/4040]
[112381201, 399920004, 312262795]
2


[1/10, 347111/602018, 56169/40328]
[2414558593225, 11553568094916, 10552837034899]
2


[1/10, 40328/56169, 5162/4549]
[236698225, 1132591716, 1185837869]
2


[1/10, 4040/9801, 93970/50201]
[112381201, 399920004, 471738797]
2


[1/10, 49/288, 2831/778]
[43099225, 71978256, 111227159]
2



For the middle column, the non-square side is the rightmost entry.
The other two members of the triad are from the (x-coordinates)/n from the curve while the first is $r$, as given. Thus we have found 7 Heron triangles with 2 square sides from rational points on the elliptic curve.
You might also notice that the first two examples actually share two square sides, $855625 = 925^2$ and $3682561 = 1919^2$ .
Thus finding rational points on $E:[0,0,0,n^2,0]$ is key to discovering more such Heron triangles with 2 square sides.
There are two special triangles where all three sides are square, they are



Triangle sides
1/2 angle tangents




$[4427^2, 4380^2, 1853^2]$
[722/699, 4320/5329, 3/34]


$[68595^2, 68104^2, 11789^2]$
[1319445/790789, 896416/1540853, 257/19729]



These two triangles satisfy a special relationship:
$ n^2 = ab + ac + bc \tag{2}$
where a,b,c are x-coordinates on the curve.
Example:
Let $E(3/34) = [0, 0, 0, 14120568900, 0]$ be an elliptic curve in Weierstrass format from $r = 3/34$ which gives $n=118830$
We find a few points on this curve:
   [0,0]
   [10485, -12215025]
   [10485, 12215025]
   [37485, -24124275]
   [37485, 24124275]
   [122740, -59851900]
   [122740, 59851900]
   [1346740, -1568952100]
   [1346740, 1568952100]
   [18458260/49, -83154461300/343]
   [18458260/49, 83154461300/343]
   [41531085/361, -384785502525/6859]
   [41531085/361, 384785502525/6859]
   [21108169/144, -124841518597/1728]
   [21108169/144, 124841518597/1728]
   [513345600/5329, -18469704121200/389017]
   [513345600/5329, 18469704121200/389017]

Let $a = 122740$ which is the $x$-coordinate for the point $[122740,59851900]$
Let $b = 10485$ which is the $x$-coordinate for the point $[10485,12215025]$
If we know two points on the curve, $a,b$, we can automatically derive the third $c$ from equation (2).
Using $a = 122740$ and $b = 10485$, we derive $c = 513345600/5329$ from $(2)$, and we can see that the last two points listed on the curve have this $x$-coordinate. Thus $c$ is a legitimate $x$-coordinate on the curve $E(3/34)$ for $a,b$.

We seek other values of $n$, or other elliptic curves $[0,0,0,n^2,0]$, such that $a,b,c$ from $3$ points on the curve satisfy $ n^2 = ab + ac + bc$ where $a,b,c$ are the $x$-coordinates of 3 points on the curve.
Can a parametric solution to (2) be found?

The text was edited, so that i can read it better. Please check if the edit is indeed an improvement. The question is clear, simply stated it wants "more" examples of elliptic curves $E_n$ with equation$$y^2=x(x^2+n^2)\ ,$$with three points $P,Q,R$ on it having $x$-coordinates respectively $a,b,c$ so that, written in a symmetric manner, $$n^2=ab+bc+ca\ .$$Some questions and comments from my side now. A brute force search delivered no "simple" examples. So it would be very useful to know more, to have a background, a motivation for the question. Why is it important, which is the origin?

I suspect some subfamily of elliptic curves of the family $(E_n)$, parametrized in some clever manner such that it comes with known points, is a first step. Do you know about any such parametrization for this family. (For the related family of congruence elliptic curves there is for instance https://people.math.ethz.ch/~halorenz/publications/pdf/rank3CNEC.pdf) Please say some more words, so that the potential answerers have a better perspective. If you have a special purpose in mind, or some usage for further examples, please share your thoughts with . Also "more examples" is one or two more?

I am sorry, but from where i am staying it is again hard to recover the details. If you use $n$ for the parameter of $E(n)$, then please do not use it again for the denominator of $1/10$ in some example. It would be simpler to mention how to pass from a rational number $r=p/q$ to the sides of a Heron triangle. In the given example, we take $n=pq(p^2+q^2)$, then $E(n)$, in the special case $r=p/q=1/10, p,q=1,10$, $n=1010$, we possibly pass to $f$, the squarefree part of $n$, but ok, here $f=n$. The points $(101,101^2)$, $((1805, 87875)$ generate $E(\Bbb Q)$. Let $P$ (or $Q$ please) be a point..

.. on $E(\Bbb Q)$, how do we pass from its coordinates to something like $$[1/10, 1659/3812, 361/202] \qquad\text{ and }\qquad [855625, 3682561, 3162054]$$from the columns of the table? Please give a reference and/or exlicit formulas. Do we need this? Or for the question we can completely ignore this aspect, and just look into the first component of points $P,Q,R$, which are $x_P,x_Q,x_R$ in notation, and want ??for the same $n$?? a relation like $$n^2=x_P x_Q + x_Q x_R+x_R x_P\ ?$$(The letters $a,b,c,n$ are inflationary used in the context. Please explain notations.)
